# Lasthead section in a longtabu environment

Tags: captions, longtable, longtabu

Longtable environment has sections for **first head** and *other* **head**.
I want to add third section for **last head** which must be on the last page of a table with slightly different text. Is it possible?

PS. I'm not sure if this question needs minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Some explanation is written in the answer of [Configure long table caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202685/51022)

It is possible. Take a look at the following code from `longtable.sty`

> ```
> \def\LT@output{%
>   \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
>     \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
>       \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
>     \else
>       \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
>       \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
>         \dimen@\pagegoal
>         \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
>         \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
>           \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
>           \@makecol
>           \@outputpage
>           \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
>         \fi
>       \fi
>       \global\@colroom\@colht
>       \global\vsize\@colht
>       \vbox
>         {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
>     \fi
>   \else
>     \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
>     \@makecol
>     \@outputpage
>       \global\vsize\@colroom
>     \copy\LT@head\nobreak%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
>   \fi}
> ```

We could see that `\ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi` is used to check whether this page is the last page. So we would like to `\copy\LT@lasthead` at this point. However, at this moment `\LT@head` is already inserted at the top of `\@cclv`. (Otherwise checking penalty does not make sense.) Therefore we need `\setbox\LT@head=\vsplit\@cclv to0pt` to remove `\LT@head` from `\@cclv`. (And return it back to `\LT@head`). But this fails since `\LT@head` in `\@cclv` follows a `\nobreak`. So we have to modify the line `\copy\LT@head\nobreak` to get the following code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,setspace}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\setstretch{5}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifmorethanonepage\morethanonepagefalse
\newbox\LT@lasthead\def\endlasthead{\LT@end@hd@ft\LT@lasthead}
\def\LT@output{%
  \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifmorethanonepage\copy\LT@lasthead\fi%%%%%
    \setbox\LT@head=\vsplit\@cclv to0pt%%%%%%
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
      \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
      \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
      \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
          \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
          \@makecol
          \@outputpage
          \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@lasthead}%
        \fi
      \fi
      \global\@colroom\@colht
      \global\vsize\@colht
      \vbox
        {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
    \fi
  \else
    \global\morethanonepagetrue%
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
    \@makecol
    \@outputpage
      \global\vsize\@colroom
    \copy\LT@head%%%%%\nobreak
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
    \caption{FIRST} \\\endfirsthead
    \caption{OTHER} \\\endhead
    \caption{LAST} \\\endlasthead
    1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\ 7 \\ 8 \\ 9 \\ 10 \\ 11 \\ 12 \\ 13 \\ 14 \\ 15 \\ 16 \\ 17 \\ 18 \\ 19 \\ 20 \\ 21 \\ 22 \\ 23 \\ 24 \\ 25 \\ 26 \\ 27 \\ 28 \\ 29 \\ 30 \\ \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```